# in python using re.py to extract from a substring error

Tags: python

I'm attending a Python course and I'm at the section on “Extracting a substring using Regex”. As an example, we are building a MAC address changer.

Here my code so far:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import optparse
import re


def get_arguments():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="interface to change its MAC address")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New MAC address")
    (options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.interface:
        parser.error("[-] please specify an interface, use --help for more info")
    elif not options.new_mac:
        parser.error("[-] please specify a MAC, use --help for more info")
    return options


def change_mac(interface, new_mac):
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "ifconfig", interface, "down"])
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
    subprocess.call(["sudo", "ifconfig", interface, "up"])
    print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)


options = get_arguments()
change_mac(options.interface, options.new_mac)

ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface])
print(ifconfig_result)
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
print(mac_address_search_result.group(0))
```

As far as I can see in the tutorial, this is how it is supposed to be, but I am getting the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “mac_changer.py”, line 32, in
mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py”, line 201, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I've looked on google for some info about this error, but I've found nothing that adapts to the mac changer.
To clarify, I am building and running this under Linux kali and it runs in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have to decode the output of `subprocess.check_output`:

```py
subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", options.interface]).decode('utf-8')
```

Take a look at the documentation of [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes. The actual encoding of the output data may depend on the command being invoked, so the decoding to text will often need to be handled at the application level.

Comment: Well i'll be, when i read your answer i was holding my reservations if this was the answer i needed even more so as i had already read simular on here for a different data set and disregarded it as been that the wrong data set, but appolagies for the doubts as i have added the decode to the ed of the line for the subprocess and now it looks like it is suposed to thanks a millionany chance of any reasonable suggestion as to why in the professional TUT video they didnt use or need to use the decode and still got the nice results?

Comment: so i have now actually just learnt a different way to deal with this issue So it turns out that i was been shown how to make my code for python 2 but was executing it as python3 so getting these errors the .decode idea worked perfectly as its the differents in string and bytes that was the issue so the different way is on the next line down after the line suggested for adding the .decode('utf-8') the line looks like this:    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)    just simply add str() around the end so str(ifconfig_result))

Comment: Yes, this is another way to go, even if I'd prefer to have `ifconfig_result` as a string.